# Define circle shape in sfml with array

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to define many `CircleShape`s by using arrays in C++
but when I use `sf::CircleShape ball[i](50);` I get a compilation error:

```
Error C2131 expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: in fact i used sf::CircleShape ball[i](50); and then above error happened

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, you can't define arrays with a size that is unknown before runtime. What you want to do is the following:

```
std::vector<sf::CircleShape> bunch_of_balls;
bunch_of_balls.resize(i, sf::CircleShape(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a built-in array with a size that is not known at compile-time. Either put the array on the heap using `new` or, preferably, use `vector` instead:

```
std::vector<sf::CircleShape> balls;
```

What do you expect the `(50)` part to do?